# To find the string that are not matching using regex pattern

Tags: c++, regex, qt, c++11, qt5

I want to return a bool value for the unmatched string

```
QRegExp rx("(?!test)");
bool unmatched = rx.exactMatch("txt"); false
if(rx.isValid()){
  return unmatched;
}
```

It returns false every time no matter what string is passed. How can I match the same values?

Comment: Your regex doesn't match anything. It has negative lookahead and nothing else.

Comment: The only string that regex will match with `exactMatch` is the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do exactly but you could iterate over the input strings and do something when any of them doesn't match a given pattern.

Notice I'm using `std::copy_if` (C++17) below, but you shouldn't need to.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/63Mr8zEx5)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // copy_if
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <iostream>  // cin
#include <iterator>  // back_inserter, istream_iterator
#include <regex>  // regex_search
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::regex pattern("test");
    std::vector<std::string> v{};
    std::copy_if(
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>{std::cin}, {},
        std::back_inserter(v), 
        [&pattern](const std::string& s) {
            return not std::regex_search(s, pattern);
    });
    fmt::print("{}", v);
}

// Input:
//
//   blah
//   foo1 test
//   foo2test
//   testfoo3
//   test

// Output:
//
//   ["blah", "foo1"]
```